# Java spring error persistence imports are not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am creating a simple Spring boot project. When I try and use @Entity and @Id etc. I get a cannot resolve error why is this? Have I not installed the correct version of something. My Imports don't seem to be working and are highlighted in red. I am new to spring. I have attached[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmlSZ.png)  as an image.

The error is Package javax.persistence does not exist??

My Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.JohnSharp</groupId>
    <artifactId>Guestbooknew</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Guestbooknew</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Please do not attach the error as an image. Post the code and the error from output as text.

Comment: show your pom.xml file please

Comment: have you tried to do a maven clean and then install? Does that work? If so, it can be an IntelliJ bug (happens every once in a while) where stuff is highlighted in red even though there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Probably because is spelled persist**e**nce and not persistance.

Comment: @DanieleTorino That's just a typo. The imports themselves seem to be correct. (see screenshot \*shivers\* )

Comment: Ah ok. Imgur is blocked at my workplace. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Right click on your project ->  Maven -> Update project.
```

For intellij:

```
Right click on your project > Maven > Reimport
```

Comment: @ShanuGuptu I cannot see update project only 'generate sources and update folders'